# Visual Basic 2010 Embedding a panel within a panel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, panel

In Visual Basic (using code) I've created a panel with multiple labels, TextBoxes, etc. that will need to be replicated within another panel.  The coding to create the repeating panel look this:

```
Public Class frmOrderEntry2

Dim a As Integer = 2
Dim x As Integer = 160

Public Sub frmOrderEntry2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '
    'This loads the module name and system date
    Dim today1 As String = Today.Date()
    txbDate.Text = today1
    txbDate.ForeColor = Color.White
    txbDate.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
    txbDate.ReadOnly = True
    txbLineNumber.Text = 1

End Sub

Private Sub btnCreateNewLine_(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateNewLine.Click

    Dim b As String = Short.Parse(a)

    'This creates the label "Part No."

    Dim lblPrtNo As New Label()
    lblPrtNo.Name = "lblPrtNo" & Convert.ToString(b)
    lblPrtNo.Text = "Part Number"
    lblPrtNo.ForeColor = Color.White
    lblPrtNo.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 9)
    lblPrtNo.Font = New Font(lblPrtNo.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    lblPrtNo.Location = New Point(13, 8)
    lblPrtNo.Size = New Size(77, 15)
    Me.Controls.Add(lblPrtNo)
    '
    'This generates the textbox for the user to enter the Part No.
    Dim txbPartNo As New TextBox()
    txbPartNo.Name = "txbPartNo" & Convert.ToString(b)
    txbPartNo.Text = ""
    txbPartNo.ForeColor = Color.Black
    txbPartNo.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    txbPartNo.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 10)
    txbPartNo.Font = New Font(txbPartNo.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    txbPartNo.Location = New Point(16, 26)
    txbPartNo.Size = New Size(263, 22)
    txbPartNo.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    txbPartNo.AcceptsReturn = True
    txbPartNo.AcceptsTab = True
    txbPartNo.TabIndex = 10
    AddHandler txbPartNo.TextChanged, AddressOf txbPartNo_Textchanged
    Me.Controls.Add(txbPartNo)
    '
    ' This generates the button control to do a part number search
    Dim btnPartNoSearch As New Button()
    btnPartNoSearch.Name = "btnPartNoSearch"
    btnPartNoSearch.Text = "S"
    btnPartNoSearch.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
    btnPartNoSearch.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Black
    btnPartNoSearch.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2
    btnPartNoSearch.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    btnPartNoSearch.TabIndex = 11
    btnPartNoSearch.ForeColor = Color.White
    btnPartNoSearch.BackColor = Color.Red
    btnPartNoSearch.Size = New Size(26, 23)
    btnPartNoSearch.Location = New Point(285, 26)
    btnPartNoSearch.Visible = True
    Me.Controls.Add(btnPartNoSearch)
'This creates the Panel and sets the labels and Textboxes to be displayed.
    Dim pnlOrderLine As New Panel()
    pnlOrderLine.Size = New Size(1577, 122)
    pnlOrderLine.Location = New Point(12, x)
    pnlOrderLine.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    pnlOrderLine.ForeColor = Color.White
    pnlOrderLine.Controls.Add(lblPrtNo)
    pnlOrderLine.Controls.Add(txbPartNo)
    pnlOrderLine.Controls.Add(btnPartNoSearch)

    a = a + 1
    x = x + 146

End Sub

Private Sub txbPartNo_Textchanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim txbPartNo As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Me.Text = txbPartNo.Name & ": " & txbPartNo.Text
    txbPartNo.Show()

End Sub
```

Using the same thought process for creating the repeating panel, I tried the following code to drop that panel into the main panel:

```
' This set the order line panel within the main panel
'Adding to main panel
pnlMainPanel.Controls.Add(pnlOrderLine)
pnlMainPanel.Visible = True
'Adding to Form i.e. me
Me.Controls.Add(pnlOrderLine)
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work.  The line panels are created but they are behind the main panel.  I need them within the main panel.

Would anyone know how to do this?

In advance, thanks for your help.

Don

Comment: The close votes are actually votes to migrate this question to Stack Overflow for you, which is where programming-related queries belong. **Don't** post a duplicate there!

Comment: You are already adding the controls to the main form, you can't add them to the other panel and expect them to display properly. You'd need to make copies and add them separately if you needed multiples OR, simply only put them in the pnlOrderLine.Controls and not Me.controls